# Redirect to parent record on create in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, action

In my simple Rails 3 application I have a has_one, has_many relationship between two models. I am passing the id of the 'owner' to the child upon creation:

**Animal Model**

```
has_many :claims, :foreign_key => 'animal_id'
has_many :conditions, :foreign_key => 'animal_id'
```

**Claim Model**

```
has_one :animal, :foreign_key => 'PVID'
has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Payment Model**

```
belongs_to :claim
```

I am passing the animal_id and claim_id to the claim and payment models respectively using hidden forms.

What I would like to do is redirect the user to the parent model upon creation. So, for example:

If the user was creating a new claim, the claim form would automatically have the animal_id inserted. What is the correct way to redirect back to the animals record?

```
format.html { redirect_to claim_animal_path, notice: 'Claim was successfully created.' }
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your routes file, the `animal_path` helper will accept an id for an animal. Something like

```
format.html { redirect_to animal_path @claim.animal.id, notice: 'Claim was successfully created.' }
```

would probably work.